# Pygame fading error when it is in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, fading

I am making an RPG in Pygame and I am having an error that is ruining the point of a fade. What is happening is that when I try to put the fading code in a function, so I don't have to have it dozens of times, it completely skips over the fading part and just flashes.

This is the working code

```
import pygame
import time

delay = time.sleep
white = 255,255,255
black = 0,0,0

pygame.display.set_caption("Liam's RPG")
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
menuIntro = False

while not menuIntro:
    menuIntro = True
    logo = pygame.image.load("logo.png").convert()
    logo.set_alpha(0)
    for alpha in range(255):
        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(logo, (100,35))     
        logo.set_alpha(alpha)
        clock.tick(200)
        pygame.display.update()
    delay(1.5)
```

This is the code that causes the fade to skip and mess up

```
import pygame
import time

delay = time.sleep
white = 255,255,255
black = 0,0,0

pygame.display.set_caption("Liam's RPG")
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
menuIntro = False

sprite = ""
fade_x = 0
fade_y = 0
clocking = clock.tick(10)

def fading(sprite,clocking,fade_x,fade_y):  
    logo = pygame.image.load(sprite + ".png").convert()
    logo.set_alpha(0)
    for alpha in range(255):
        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(logo, (fade_x,fade_y))     
        logo.set_alpha(alpha)
        clocking

while not menuIntro:
    menuIntro = True
    sprite = 'logo'
    fade_x = 100
    fade_y = 35
    clocking = clock.tick(200)
    fading(sprite,clocking,fade_x,fade_y)
    pygame.display.update()
    delay(1.5)
```

[Here is the logo thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Quk.png) that I am trying to fade in, it needs to be in the same directory as the file

Comment: variable `clocking` is not function. It doesn't slow down you fading. compare both code - they are different. you forgot to `update()` screen inside `for` loop in `fading()`.

Comment: @furas I have tried replacing it with just normal clock.tick(x) and it does the same thing. Also if you look above the delay you can see where I update the code

Comment: you update in wrong place. you have to update after every `blit` in `for alpha`. Now you update only once when `for alpha` is finished.

Comment: the same problem is with `tick()`

Comment: @furas It is now working, however removing clocking and clock.tick does not change the speed of the fade

Comment: removing `clocking` nothing change because `clocing` is useless - it is not function - it only keeps value returned by `clock.tick()`. Put `clock.tick(10)` inside `for alpha` to slow down fading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In correct code you have `tick` and `update` inside `for alpha` loop. In incorrect code you have `tick` and `update` outside this loop - and it doesn't work as you expect.